# Adding new markers on map using cluster manager doesn't reflect the changes until I zoom in and zoom out the map

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, android-maps-utils

When I add new markers on the map programmatically using cluster manager it doesn't reflect the changes until I update the zoom in and zoom out.

I have seen lots of questions on stack overflow  but that doesn't work for me,

So please tell me how to update the map without clearing the map.

Code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
 { 
   Person_marker person_marker = new Person_marker(createRandLocation(latLng),
   name[i], getAddress(latLng), typedArray.getResourceId(i, -1), time[i], acuracy[i]);
   person_markerList.add(person_marker);
 } 
clusterManager.clearItems(); clusterManager.addItems(person_markerList);
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @JamieRees for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
   
    Person_marker person_marker = new Person_marker(createRandLocation(latLng), name[i], getAddress(latLng), typedArray.getResourceId(i, -1), time[i], acuracy[i]);
    
    person_markerList.add(person_marker);
    
    
   }
       
   clusterManager.clearItems();
   clusterManager.addItems(person_markerList);



here is the code through which i am clearing the existing marker and adding new marker on map.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After adding all the markers, if you call `clusterManager.cluster()` it will draw what's been previsouly added.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 Very nice, helped me! Where is that documented? Google's clustering demo does not use that, https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/ClusteringDemoActivity.java

Comment: You're right, I don't see it documented properly anywhere, but if you open the code of the ClusterManager (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) and check the cluster method, the javadoc does say that you may wanna call it after adding new items.